# How to dynamically restrict duplicated value of <input='text'/> in a looped random value from <input='number'/> field

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, validation, duplicates

```js
$('#inputqty').on('change keyup',function(){
  let inputs='';
  let value = parseInt($(this).val());
  if (0<value) {
    for (let i = 0; i<value; i++) {
      inputs+=`<div style="margin-left: 10px; margin-top: 10px;">
                <input autocomlete="off" type="text" style="margin-bottom:5px;margin-top:5px; margin-left:10px;"  name="item_serial" id="serial_number" placeholder=" Serial Number. item:${i+1}" tabindex="${i+6+1}" required /></br>
              </div>`
      }
  }
  else{
    inputs+=`<center>No item Quantity inputted!!!<center>`
    }
  $('#contentforserial').html(inputs);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="number" min="1" max="10"id="inputqty" name="inputqty">

<div style="height: 190px;width:260px;padding:3px; background:greenyellow;" id="containerforserial">
    <div>Enter Serial Number of Item:</div>
    <div class="contentforserial" id="contentforserial" style="  height:150px;overflow:auto;background:#fff;">
      <div id="demo"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Create an `object` which will be used as database to store input values. Loop through input elements and store value as key in the `object` and an array as key. Push input element in the array.
Then loop through `object` values (array of input elements) and if array contains more than one input element, that means these input elements have duplicate values, do whatever you want with them:

```js
const myInputs = document.getElementById("myinputs");

document.getElementById("inputqty").addEventListener("input", onInput);

onInput.bind(document.getElementById("inputqty"))();

function onInput(e)
{
  const value = Math.max(~~this.value, 0);
  // show/hide message
  noinputs.classList.toggle("hidden", value > 0);
  let i = 1;
  //create new inputs
  while(myInputs.children.length < value)
  {
    const input = document.createElement("input");
    input.className = "serial_number";
    input.id = `serial_number${i}`;
    input.name = "item_serial[]";
    input.placeholder = `Serial Number. item:${i}`;
    input.tabIndex = `${i+6}`;
    input.autocomplete = "off";
    input.required = true;
    input.addEventListener("input", checkInputs);
    myInputs.appendChild(input);
    i++;
  }
  //remove excess inputs
  while(myInputs.children.length > value)
    myInputs.removeChild(myInputs.lastChild);

  //make sure we check for duplcates again in case inputs were removed
  checkInputs();
};

function checkInputs(e)
{
  //generate list of values from all inputs
  const values = {};
  for(let i = 0; i < myInputs.children.length; i++)
  {
    const value = myInputs.children[i].value.trim();
    if (!values[value])
      values[value] = [];

    values[value].push(i);
  }
  //check if multiple inputs have the same value
  for(let value in values)
  {
    const inputs = values[value];
    for(let i = 0, count = inputs.length; i < count; i++)
    {
      const input = myInputs.children[inputs[i]];
      input.classList.toggle("error", value !== "" && count > 1);
    }

  }
}
```

```css
.error
{
  background-color: red;
}

#myinputs > input
{
  margin-bottom:5px;
  margin-top:5px;
  margin-left:10px;
}

#noinputs.hidden
{
  display: none;
}

#containerforserial
{
  height: 190px;
  width:260px;
  padding:3px;
  background:greenyellow;
}

#contentforserial
{
  height:150px;
  overflow:auto;
  background:#fff;
}
```

```html
<input type="number" min="1" max="10" id="inputqty" name="inputqty" value="1">

<div id="containerforserial">
  <div>Enter Serial Number of Item:</div>
  <div class="contentforserial" id="contentforserial">
    <div id="myinputs"></div>
    <center id="noinputs">No item Quantity inputted!!!</center>
    <div id="demo"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And please avoid using bloatware jquery and inline styles.

Comment: How About i inputed a text and when i add another qty of item, it will not reset to blank space. but anyways thanks for the help <3

Answer (score 1):

You can create one function to check duplicate value then on your input add onchange event call to this function

Example

```
function checkForDuplicates() {      
    var valuesAlreadySeen = []
    $(".serial_number").each(function() {
        if($(this).val() != ""){
          if (valuesAlreadySeen.indexOf( $(this).val() ) !== -1) {
            /* do some thing here */
            alert( $(this).val()+' already input' );
            
            /* clear this input */
            $(this).val("");
          }else{
            valuesAlreadySeen.push( $(this).val() );
          }
        }        
    });
  
}
```

Then add class and on change event to your input

```
<input class="serial_number" onchange="checkForDuplicates()" />
```

So, your final code should be

```
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <input type="number" min="1" max="10"id="inputqty" name="inputqty">
        
        <div style="height: 190px;width:260px;padding:3px; background:greenyellow;" id="containerforserial">
            <div>Enter Serial Number of Item:</div>
            <div class="contentforserial" id="contentforserial" style="  height:150px;overflow:auto;background:#fff;">
              <div id="demo"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $('#inputqty').on('change keyup',function(){
        let inputs='';
        let value = parseInt($(this).val());
        if (0<value) {
          for (let i = 0; i<value; i++) {
            inputs+=`<div style="margin-left: 10px; margin-top: 10px;">
                <input class="serial_number" onchange="checkForDuplicates()" autocomlete="off" type="text" style="margin-bottom:5px;margin-top:5px; margin-left:10px;"  name="item_serial[]" placeholder=" Serial Number. item:${i+1}" tabindex="${i+6+1}" required /></br>
              </div>`
          }
        }
        else{
          inputs+=`<center>No item Quantity inputted!!!<center>`
        }
        $('#contentforserial').html(inputs);
      });
    });
    
    function checkForDuplicates() {
         
        var valuesAlreadySeen = []
        $(".serial_number").each(function() {
            if($(this).val() != ""){
              if (valuesAlreadySeen.indexOf( $(this).val() ) !== -1) {
                /* do some thing here */
                alert( $(this).val()+' already input' );
                $(this).val("");/* clear this input */
              }else{
                valuesAlreadySeen.push( $(this).val() );
              }
            }        
        });
      
    }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a class name to your input text inside the loop then

```
var array = $('.className').map(function(){
  return $(this).val()
}).get();
```

this array will give you values of input fields, you can validate it, and add the validation error message to the relevant input field using the index of the array.